# How to index string within array?

Tags: arrays, list, substring

I'm trying to get index of string within array.

What would be the most proper and fast way of doing so?

Comment: Why do you program with python 2 and not 3?

Comment: @knurzl - how is that germane to the question again?

Comment: @knurzl What do you mean? Is one known to be better than the other?

Comment: I'm just interested in because I Programm with 3 because it's newer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your main list is: `your_arr`, and the multiple substring list is: `multiple`:

```
def find_multiple_substring(your_arr, multiple):
    res = [i for i, item in enumerate(your_arr) if all(x in item for x in multiple)]
    return res[0] if res else -1
```

You'd call it as:

```
x = ["pink-one", "pink-two", "pink-three", "pink-four"]
y = ["pink", "one"]  # For a search to be successful, all of these
                     # strings should be present in `x`.
find_multiple_substring(x, y)   # returns 0
```

Comment: Is your method faster than others? If so do you mind explaining the logic for learning purposes? Thank you in advance

Comment: It runs in O(mn), and is very similar to others answers posted, if that answers your question..

Answer (score 2):

How about a class that inherits from `list` with a new method?

```
class DualIndexList(list):
    def dual_index(lst, first, second):
        for ix, l in enumerate(lst):
            if first in l and second in l:
                return ix
        return -1

mylist = DualIndexList(["pink-one", "pink-two", "pink-three", "pink-four"])

print mylist.dual_index("pink", "one")
```

Result: `0`

You could also make this infinitely extensible:

```
class NthIndexList(list):
    def nth_index(lst, *args):
        for ix, l in enumerate(lst):
            count = 0
            arglength = len(args)
            for arg in args:
                if arg in l:
                    count += 1
                else:
                    continue
                if count == arglength:
                    return ix
        return -1

mylist = NthIndexList(["pink-one-a", "pink-two-b", "pink-three-c", "pink-four-d"])

print mylist.nth_index("pink", "one", "a")
```

Result: `0`

Comment: would it not work for integers list? How can I convert every element in a list to strings?

Comment: You can convert the list items to strings like this: `newlist = [str(i) for i in oldlist]`

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list comprehension to give back all such instances:

```
>>> a = ["pink-one", "pink-two", "pink-three", "pink-four"]
>>> q = "one"
>>> sub_indices = lambda query,lib: [i for i,x in enumerate(lib) if query in x]
>>> sub_indices(q,a)
[0]
>>>
```

Comment: Don't use `lambda` if you are going to assign it to a name. The whole point today of `lambda` is to create an *anonymous* function. Use the `def` statement in this case.

Comment: But its very compact and if you just need it one ore two times its ok.

Comment: @knurzl It is explicitly against PEP8. But do whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

I think that would be the easiest way if you just want to match the first result:

```
lst = [“pink-one”, “pink-two”, “pink-three”, “pink-four”]

print(lst.index([x for x in lst if 'one' in x][0]))
```

Another option would be lambda:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: 'one' in x, lst))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient method to find one index or all indexes (indices) that contain the substrings you are looking for.

```
def index_with_substrings(l, substrings):
  return next(indexes_with_substrings(l, substrings), None)

def indexes_with_substrings(l, substrings):
  for i, element in enumerate(l):
    if all(substring in element for substring in substrings): 
      yield i
  raise StopIteration()


l = ['pink-one', 'pink-two', 'pink-three', 'pink-four']
print(index_with_substrings(l, ['pink', 'one']))    # 0
print(index_with_substrings(l, ['pink', 'three']))  # 2
print(index_with_substrings(l, ['pink', 'five']))   # None
print(list(indexes_with_substrings(l, ['pink'])))   # [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/ITuU/0.js"></script>
```